# Limiting length of field when outputting

Tags: mongodb

I'm storing some large html document in my collection. Is there a way I can limit the character length in the fields output when doing a query? This is just for easier visualization while testing queries.

For example, given a very long html document, truncate the field to 50 characters or so in the terminal:

```
{
    "name": "something",
    "html": "<!doctype html><html itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {name: "something"}},
  {$project: {html: {$substrCP: ["$html",0,50]}}}
])
```

This uses the [`$substrCP` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/#exp._S_substrCP) of expression objects.

I'll also point out, using an aggregation pipeline might be overkill. If you just want to omit the html field entirely from an output, you can use a [simple projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/):

```
db.collection.find({name: "something"}, {html: 0})
```